# In ggplot2 - how to ensure geom_errorbar displays bar limits for all points when controlling x-axis with xlim()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to produce a fairly simple plot of a proportion against an integer valued predictor. I am using geom_errorbar to display uncertainty for each point estimate.

e.g.

```
require(ggplot2)
mydata <- data.frame(my_x = 70:99, 
                     my_y = seq(0.7,0.3,length.out=30), 
                     my_lower = seq(0.6,0.2,length.out=30), 
                     my_upper = seq(0.8,0.4,length.out=30))

ggplot(mydata,aes(x=my_x)) + geom_point(aes(y=my_y)) +
                           geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=my_lower, ymax=my_upper)) +
                           xlim(70,80)
```

For largely aesthetic reasons I am using xlim() to set the x-axis limits (as you do). But this removes the horizontal lines indicating the limits of the error bars at the min and max x-values. I presume this is because `ggplot2` is trying to draw a line which lies outside of the plot region (the function call prints some warnings from `geom_path` about missing values).

[image: badggplot]

I could clean the data of the unwanted rows beforehand or include a `subset` statement in the `ggplot` call, but I feel like there is/should be a cleaner solution when zooming into a plot. Any ideas?

Comment: This behaviour of ggplot2 is most annoying. Lucky you it didn't kill the errorbars completely, because one point isn't on the chart anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Bit hacky but it seems to work:

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=my_x)) + geom_point(aes(y=my_y)) +
                           geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=my_lower, ymax=my_upper)) +
                           coord_cartesian(xlim=c(69.5,80.5))
```

Comment: This works, but you are right it seems a bit hacky. Having browsed similar problems online it appears subsetting the data is the optimal solution, though I think it would be nice for this to be dealt with separately from the data. Ta

Answer (score 0):

You can try reduce the width of the error bar.

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=my_x)) + geom_point(aes(y=my_y)) +
                           geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=my_lower, ymax=my_upper),width=0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with doing this with a date scale, where I was specifying the following arguments:

```
scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y %B", 
               date_breaks = "1 month",
               limits=as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2021-11-01"), format="%y-%m-%d"),
               )
```

Eventually solved the problem with:

```
scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y %B", 
                   # date_breaks = "1 month",
                   limits=as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2021-11-01"), format="%y-%m-%d"),
                   breaks = seq(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2021-11-01"), by="months"))
```