# Revisiting R+ggplot+geom_bar+scale_x_continuous+limits: leftmost and rightmost bars not showing on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Please don't tag this as a duplicate of [R+ggplot+geom_bar+scale_x_continuous+limits: leftmost and rightmost bars not showing on plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585428/rggplotgeom-barscale-x-continuouslimits-leftmost-and-rightmost-bars-not-sho) :** some people commented that the example in there was too long/convoluted/weird, so here is a simpler example that reproduces the problem. If a moderator think it is a good idea I will delete the original (longer) question.

I am trying to create a function that does a stacked bar plot of some yearly measures. The function takes as parameters the data and the min and max year I want to plot. The problem is that for some combination of the years the bars get weird.

Here is the code, it defines the function, creates a simple simulated dataset and creates four plots with different parameters. The resulting images are below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Plot either all data or select by name.
doPlot <- function(data,minYear,maxYear) {
  title = paste("Bob's Performance ",minYear,"-",maxYear)
  # Aggregate quantity by year and category
  byYear <- aggregate(Quantity ~ Year+Category, data, sum)
  # Get coordinates for numbers in stacked bars
  byYear = ddply(byYear, "Year", mutate, label_y = cumsum(Quantity))
  g <- ggplot(byYear, aes(x=Year,y=Quantity))
  g <- g + geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=Category), colour="black") + 
    ggtitle(title) +
      scale_fill_discrete("Category",labels=c("Sheep","Cactus","Chicken"),drop=FALSE,c=45, l=80)+
      scale_x_continuous(name="Year", limits=c(minYear,maxYear), breaks=seq(minYear,maxYear,1)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=Quantity,y=label_y), vjust=1.3,size=6)
  print(g)
}

consts = paste('"Category","Year","Name","Quantity"\n', 
               'CACTUS,1997,Bob,45\n',
               'CHICKEN,1997,Bob,6\n',
               'SHEEP,1998,Bob,2\n',
               'SHEEP,1999,Bob,4\n',
               'SHEEP,2005,Bob,5\n',sep = "")
data <- read.csv(text=consts,header = TRUE)
data$Category <- factor(data$Category, levels = c("SHEEP", "CACTUS", "CHICKEN"))

# This works OK
doPlot(data,1996,2006)
# This don't: bars on left and rightside disappears
doPlot(data,1997,2005)
# This don't: left bar disappears but it seems it was not plotted.
doPlot(data,1998,2000)
# This is weird: why does the bar width uses over 5 years?
doPlot(data,1999,2011)
```

The first plot is OK since the data is all inside the years range:

[image]

In the second plot the years range is exactly the same as the range of years in the data. The leftmost and rightmost bars are not plotted, but the numbers are.

[image]

In the third plot the year range is very narrow -- again leftmost and/or rightmost bars are not plotted. There's a hint here that the bar width could not be fitted in the plot -- see the width for 1999!

[image]

The fourth plot the year range is wider, but again leftmost and/or rightmost bars are not plotted, and the one bar that is plotted covers several years.

[image]

I can make the plot sort of work by using always an extended range for years, but this is bugging me. I guess I didn't specify something that controls the bar widths, but what?

I noticed that there are similar problems with the leftmost and rightmost bars, e.g. [In ggplot2 - how to ensure geom_errorbar displays bar limits for all points when controlling x-axis with xlim()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303861/in-ggplot2-how-to-ensure-geom-errorbar-displays-bar-limits-for-all-points-when) , and the solutions are similar, but I believe there ought to be a better way.

I must point out that using

```
scale_x_continuous(name="Year", breaks=seq(minYear,maxYear,1)) + 
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(minYear,maxYear)) +
```

instead of

```
scale_x_continuous(name="Year", limits=c(minYear,maxYear),breaks=seq(minYear,maxYear,1)) +
```

solves the "bar over several years" issue of the fourth plot, but causes parts of the leftmost/rightmost bars to be plotted:

[image]

thanks
Rafael